# How to update array of object in mongodb using express js and mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

TypeError: result.taskList[id].push is not a function

[image: 1]

```
const taskcancel = (user, pswd, id) => {
return db.Todotasks.findOne({ username: user, password: pswd }).then((result) => {
        if (result) {
            console.log(result.taskList[id])
            result.taskList[id].push({
                taskStatus:'canceled',
            });
            result.taskCount.pendingTask -= 1,
                result.taskCount.canceledTask += 1,
                result.save()
            return {
                status: true,
                message: ('Successfully canceled your tasks'),
                statusCode: 200,
            }
        } else {
            return {
                status: false,
                message: ('Somthing went wrong try again'),
                statusCode: 404
            }

        }
    })
```

I need to update taskStatus of taskList but I got an error TypeError: result.taskList[id].push is not a function. how to resolve this error? database mongodB

Comment: Is `id` an index of a task ?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that `result.taskList[id]` is not an array.

Change it to :

```
const taskcancel = (user, pswd, id) => {
  return db.Todotasks.findOne({ username: user, password: pswd }).then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      console.log(result.taskList[id])
      result.taskList[id].taskStatus = 'canceled';
      result.taskCount.pendingTask -= 1;
      result.taskCount.canceledTask += 1;
      return result.save().then(() => {
        return {
          status: true,
          message: ('Successfully canceled your tasks'),
          statusCode: 200,
        };
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return {
          status: false,
          message: ('Something went wrong while saving the changes'),
          statusCode: 500,
        };
      });
    } else {
      return {
        status: false,
        message: ('Something went wrong try again'),
        statusCode: 404
      };
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I am already tried this method but not working, database value not changed..

Comment: @Josiey I updated the code. Can you test ?

Comment: yes bro.. its not working..  TypeError: result.taskList[id].push is not a function